# How to make following code execute once require() has completed? Require JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs, require

I would like to know how to ensure the method `doStuffWithModules(modules)` is executed once method `require()` has completed execution.

For example:

```
var moduleNames = ['moduleOne', 'moduleTwo'], //An array of module names, which could be of any length
    modules = [];

require(moduleNames, function() {

    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        modules.push(arguments[i]);
    }
});

doStuffWithModules(modules);
```

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move `doStuffWithModules` into the `require` function:

```
var moduleNames = ['moduleOne', 'moduleTwo'];
//An array of module names, which could be of any length

require(moduleNames, function() {
    var modules = []
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        modules.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    doStuffWithModules(modules);
});
```

Comment: Of course! Sometimes I feel that I am blind to the simplest solutions.